# Поместить скролл на начало документа при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пробовал так:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Пробовал эдак:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
```

Но всё же, если зайти на середину страницы, нажать "обновить", скролл всё равно уйдет к тому месту, где был в прошлый раз. Как переместить на начало при любом обновлении (в идеале - предотвратить любой анкор тоже, но это опционально)?

Comment: @Yuri, Что значит "скроллится нормально"? Оно не должно нормально скроллиться, а при обновлении должно перемещаться на начало страницы. А браузер всё равно возвращает на то место, где был до того, как нажал на кнопку "обновить".
Какая жизнь, такие и вопросы :)

Comment: В смысле? Я прокручиваю страницу, обновляю её и JS поднимает скролл вверх

Comment: @Yuri, вот тебе [pen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/oBzKYm), а вот тебе [дебаг](http://s.codepen.io/VostokSisters/debug/oBzKYm/NQAzYvQbnWyr). Открой дебаг, заскроль до середины и обнови - окажешься там же.

Comment: @Yuri, ну да, было бы круто :D И впрямь работает. Хотя на локальном хосте - нифига не работает...  Даже и не понимаю в чем проблема. Такой же код используется.

Comment: А чем плох вопрос, можете объяснить? Мне кажется вполне актуальным.

Comment: @Yuri Например, страница этого вопроса по Ctrl-R и Ctrl-F5 обновляется, но прокрутка остаётся там, где была, к началу не возвращается.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image" style="width:300px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati esse voluptates ratione, aspernatur quis. Quo magni provident omnis ex illum! Rem vero reiciendis quasi id, enim quos recusandae expedita molestias mollitia obcaecati nam ut iure maxime fuga, nobis harum porro animi nisi praesentium, iusto qui earum velit quisquam. Debitis nisi sed assumenda libero itaque quae, incidunt necessitatibus recusandae consectetur atque asperiores voluptatem molestiae accusantium animi laborum eos, omnis, corrupti aut? Aperiam error facere at expedita molestiae modi velit, autem nisi maxime, consequuntur ea dignissimos asperiores provident ullam quia doloribus numquam deserunt ducimus soluta voluptas ratione magnam quos. Totam adipisci placeat quo consectetur ducimus, obcaecati provident minima similique maxime officiis, nostrum quae! Incidunt mollitia ratione consequatur quisquam dolores deleniti, minus laborum adipisci reiciendis. Eligendi ad, nam quaerat quod eius laboriosam, dignissimos, voluptatibus aut ab optio sapiente quia totam sed expedita fugiat modi dolor, tenetur facere non reprehenderit itaque adipisci. Autem nostrum assumenda voluptatibus, velit reprehenderit consequatur dignissimos voluptatem in perferendis aspernatur pariatur quae ab, neque similique enim blanditiis repellat aut optio? Enim repellat, accusantium cumque dolor, nostrum eum aliquid. Ex eaque, ducimus consequatur, architecto, velit vel quia est culpa a et veniam! Magni eaque necessitatibus hic iste, ipsam saepe! Ex, excepturi? Iure labore vero voluptatibus velit quisquam iste id? Nobis nam, suscipit soluta ipsum, quisquam deserunt adipisci officiis id nesciunt mollitia obcaecati cum enim molestias eum velit laborum quasi sed dicta odit, minima aspernatur reiciendis odio! Modi ratione vel culpa sed ipsum, magnam doloremque minima saepe, dolores voluptatum velit harum recusandae, non dolorum laborum rerum. Totam natus odio quis architecto, et aut repudiandae itaque veritatis id reiciendis aperiam velit sed molestias consectetur magni aliquam, nam asperiores. Architecto quia ullam officiis id placeat veniam at quaerat. Assumenda explicabo ea aperiam commodi eveniet sunt magni doloribus illum aliquid architecto laboriosam corrupti officia exercitationem corporis totam, aliquam quo est earum ullam eum iusto voluptas reiciendis, odit sit error. Tempore, facere sequi culpa nisi accusamus doloremque voluptas natus minima, modi soluta sint, repellat ut dolores illum ipsam atque voluptatem praesentium. Molestias dolorum repudiandae officiis nemo praesentium inventore aut in, excepturi repellat, nesciunt magni adipisci sapiente dolore eligendi, unde vel iusto. Assumenda iusto, quae nostrum quasi non veniam facere dicta deserunt temporibus distinctio hic soluta, deleniti similique harum, nihil rerum voluptatum repellendus vitae sequi magni quis. Molestiae vel dolore laboriosam explicabo fugiat debitis corporis perspiciatis sequi deleniti doloremque dolorum porro molestias alias aspernatur libero nemo unde praesentium, fugit ab eum? Fugit corporis eos laborum aut excepturi, saepe quidem facilis vitae quae delectus ipsam qui numquam alias animi, possimus est hic nesciunt velit consectetur necessitatibus eligendi exercitationem? Nostrum, suscipit! Delectus eaque magni dolore, accusantium reprehenderit nostrum laudantium maiores aperiam, ad vitae, neque. Inventore ea eum ipsa, placeat minima amet provident qui similique, cumque quidem natus voluptate, ut odio. Ad aliquam dolore mollitia perferendis fugiat deserunt incidunt veniam, voluptatibus praesentium ipsum amet quidem. Totam voluptatem nobis qui doloribus temporibus, mollitia voluptas commodi soluta explicabo maxime ipsam debitis ducimus sit, possimus tempore incidunt excepturi quasi architecto ut asperiores? Deleniti temporibus molestias tenetur porro, eius necessitatibus praesentium obcaecati dolorem assumenda, nihil illum itaque quae minima fugit esse laborum corrupti est perferendis inventore? Consequuntur facere eos recusandae, repellat aperiam in suscipit earum, similique, beatae illum accusamus laudantium quasi. Dolorum in quo, provident similique. Iusto eaque sapiente modi perspiciatis, corporis beatae vitae excepturi alias quisquam, voluptates, possimus quidem tempora repellendus expedita, praesentium reiciendis natus error culpa eveniet. Minus nesciunt inventore voluptatum cum molestiae debitis amet dolores eius, culpa itaque, labore placeat suscipit non beatae accusamus aliquid, autem voluptates? Non dolorem fugiat quo fuga veritatis architecto eaque dicta totam ab sequi sit a earum aut, deleniti nihil repellat itaque aliquid perferendis quos enim quibusdam dolore ullam illum nostrum! Nihil mollitia quibusdam vel, eum eveniet incidunt, nesciunt modi necessitatibus explicabo amet quasi fuga asperiores dolor quas iste, laudantium consequuntur harum! Inventore error maiores aut quasi! Repudiandae ut nostrum, consectetur quos explicabo ipsam, fugiat qui at deserunt ex tempore sequi autem blanditiis labore et quidem reiciendis itaque, veniam? Sit, ipsum ipsam, culpa magnam totam unde iste repellat! Voluptates, necessitatibus. Praesentium, voluptatibus, reprehenderit. Sapiente soluta aspernatur eos delectus! Enim itaque, porro, sapiente perferendis assumenda voluptatum voluptatem maiores ut dolorem numquam quidem, consectetur amet. Esse, quidem. Facere omnis ratione deserunt labore fugit voluptatibus recusandae vero, placeat delectus adipisci quod fugiat vel nemo sit totam, itaque quis aliquid porro, quaerat similique error nam repellat asperiores. Tempora, omnis, animi? Nam aspernatur numquam quos vero, ipsa officia dolores ratione delectus voluptas aliquam neque repellendus odit obcaecati, a quisquam odio. Obcaecati, necessitatibus pariatur delectus labore quia, aspernatur provident maiores dolores consequatur eaque ut! Eveniet aspernatur cupiditate alias eos eaque minus, autem, iure nam expedita dolor voluptas libero, et provident, deleniti sunt sed officiis eligendi recusandae nemo. Laudantium alias facilis iusto, unde beatae odit, dolorem debitis cumque accusantium nihil culpa, quam quo ab inventore hic. Esse, ut, libero! Nam laborum commodi soluta laboriosam quia, quaerat nemo pariatur totam rerum asperiores consectetur assumenda quae obcaecati, natus voluptas earum placeat! Beatae labore dolores eveniet, est. Nihil facere itaque, ab perferendis enim velit fugiat asperiores dolor architecto laboriosam consequatur pariatur sed cumque quia sit neque, earum, reprehenderit at accusantium amet expedita! Repellat doloribus ratione molestiae, optio sint officiis et expedita suscipit quidem aliquid quod possimus perferendis, quibusdam nam! Neque aliquam inventore sunt, quia error laudantium officia, necessitatibus quo culpa molestiae fuga animi minima placeat similique porro. Dignissimos voluptas maiores dolores at, eos, tenetur atque iure deserunt debitis porro ratione natus nisi officia quis iste consectetur tempora nulla mollitia ullam animi. Adipisci odit amet, impedit. Commodi voluptate, rerum eius ratione perferendis, optio quia, enim hic voluptatum autem molestias obcaecati culpa voluptatibus, voluptas iste asperiores quasi natus! Error sed ut velit, quasi tempore illo cum nihil temporibus, eligendi deleniti saepe ipsam. Earum a, fugit voluptate quos recusandae facere possimus architecto natus, ea atque suscipit adipisci dolor magni eum dicta, minus aut vitae. Minima laboriosam distinctio quidem fugit deleniti ullam quis eveniet obcaecati pariatur consequatur, explicabo ab reiciendis, perferendis totam ducimus voluptates laborum dolorum quia animi ad atque.
</div>
```